# Is it possible in QGIS print composer to include a numeric scale in an html box?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, print-composer, qgis-2.2, qgis-2.4

For work I always have to create a table with my name, project name, date etc. into my map layouts. I also need to include the scale like "1:150000" in that table.

So far I am solving that by including an html table with the html box function of the print composer. Is there a way to automatically include the right scale? So far I only managed to automatically include the date by using a little javascript. Maybe something similar is also possible for the scale?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing but for the date I could recommend another 'native' way: `[%day($now)||'.'||month($now)||'.'||Year($now)%]` This expression will be processed by QGIS.

Answer (score 6):

Tested with QGIS 3.6.1

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#layout-functions), you can create a label and insert this code to get the current scale for the map with the item name `Map 0`:

```
map_get( item_variables('Map 0'), 'map_scale')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can register expression function to get your map scale. For example:

```
from qgis.utils import iface 

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_composer_map_scale(comp_window_title, feature, parent):
    composer_views = iface.activeComposers()
    my_composition = None
    for view in composer_views:
        if view.window().windowTitle() == comp_window_title:
            my_composition = view.composition()
            break
    if my_composition is not None:
        # adjust map id below if you have more maps in the composer
        comp_map = my_composition.getComposerMapById(0)
        scale = '{:.0f}'.format(round(comp_map.scale(), 0))
        return scale
    else:
        return 'Unknown'
```

And use it in your HTML box or label:

```
Scale 1:[%get_composer_map_scale( 'Composer 1' )%]
```

where 'Composer 1' is your composer title.

Comment: I'm assuming that the new QGIS 3 API breaks this function, is that correct?

Comment: This is an outdated answer (only works for qgis 2).