# Integrating numeric scales into a text or HTML box in QGIS print composer.

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am trying to embed the scale of a map in the print composer expression builder or HTML frame. Effectively the value of the scale in the map item properties would come through into the text and be used as part of a standard text or HTML. This seems to be related to question:

> [Is it possible in QGIS print composer to include a numeric scale in an html box?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110332/is-it-possible-in-qgis-print-composer-to-include-a-numeric-scale-in-an-html-box)

In QGIS 2.6 (and earlier versions) there is an option to use the scale as part of an expression, however, it isn't possible to use this function in the Print Composer - I think it is probably to do with the need to stipulate which map item you are interested in the scale of (this doesn't seem to be possible using the scale function in the expression builder).

Can anyone suggest an alternative way of doing this or is what I suggest not possible and one to be captured as an enhancement request?

I am using QGIS 2.6 in Windows 7.