# How to add scale text in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm using QGIS 2.18.4, I wanted to add "scale text" but can't find the tool for adding the scale text on the composer. I only see an option of add text and not "scale text" as in other GIS Software like ArcGIS. Is there anyone who knows this?

Comment: You dont know what you want. Who need scaled text? Try with font size.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to add a numeric scale like 1:10000 you can add a normal scalebar first and then change the style to 'Numeric' under *Item Properties > Main Properties* of the scalebar element.

Answer (score 3):

You can register expression function to get your map scale. For example:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface 

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def get_composer_map_scale(comp_window_title, feature, parent):
    composer_views = iface.activeComposers()
    my_composition = None
    for view in composer_views:
        if view.window().windowTitle() == comp_window_title:
            my_composition = view.composition()
            break
    if my_composition is not None:
        # adjust map id below if you have more maps in the composer
        comp_map = my_composition.getComposerMapById(0)
        scale = '{:.0f}'.format(round(comp_map.scale(), 0))
        return scale
    else:
        return 'Unknown'
```

And use it in your HTML box or label:

```py
Scale 1:[%get_composer_map_scale( 'Composer 1' )%]
```

where 'Composer 1' is your composer title.

Answer (score 3):

In QGis 3.x you can add variables in text item with something like `[%'1 : '  || round(map_get(item_variables('Main'), 'map_scale'),0)%]`

Comment: Thanks for posting an updated information. Unfortunatly its not working. Does someone know which function queries the live map scale?

Comment: I have tested, it works. You have to remplace "Main" with the name of your map (you find this information in the field "Item ID - id". You can also add a scalebar and choose the style "numeric"

Comment: Thanks a lot. You kinda opened a whole new world to me there. Will give the variables closer attention now :)

Answer (score 2):

Same as these?:

- [Integrating numeric scales into a text or HTML box in QGIS print
  composer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/133045/92255)
- [Is it possible in QGIS print composer to include a
  numeric scale in an html box?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/110332/92255)

According to [OSGEO - QGIS developer](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/map-scale-as-a-variable-in-map-composer-html-label-td5310497.html) it is not possible, but it will be in version 3.0. [GitHub commit](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/f2032ea2688715163a631cc0860b9e5f97257cfc).