# Which expression are working in the HTML frame in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, html

I'm using the HTML frame in the print composer. I would like to automatically insert data like $scale and the name field of the Atlas layer. Till now I only got the date working `[%day($now)||'.'||month($now)||'.'||Year($now)%]`. Is there a list of which expression are supposed to be working inside the HTML frame?

Comment: The question is related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110332/is-it-possible-in-qgis-print-composer-to-include-a-numeric-scale-in-an-html-box

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?