# How can I calculate the canvas scale in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, scale, atlas

Using the atlas functionality in QGIS 2.14 The canvas scale varies according to the object in question (national parks).

I want to have a numbered scale based on the canvas print size.  I tried using scale in a text box:

```
[% $scale %]
```

This gives me "0" and is not useful. Either this is an error, or I am not using it right.

Requesting pagewidth and dpi works fine. Is there a different way to do this? Based on pagewidth and real world maxx and minx I should be able to calculate the scale. But I can not find any variables for maxx and minx.

How can I present scale on the atlas generated maps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert a scale bar in the normal way, then change the `Style` drop down to `Numeric` and you will get a scale as 1:XXXXX

[image]

Comment: Good and precise answer to my question. Still wondering why the scale variable does not give a proper value.

Comment: The help on $scale mentions that it is only available in some contexts.  My understanding is that you use this in conjunction with other functions, rather than as a return for a value

Comment: To insert current map's scale value in label as text see this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/332759/35561

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a standalone number, a numeric scalebar is fine but if you want to insert the scale value into a label, a function is required.

(From the QGIS documentation)

Choose "Insert an expression...", "Function Editor" and paste the following (Also give the function list a name and click "Load")

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Composer')
def composeritemattr(composername, mapname, attrname, feature, parent):
    composers = iface.activeComposers()
    # Find the composer with the given name
    comp = [composer.composition() for composer in composers 
                if composer.composerWindow().windowTitle() == composername][0]
    # Find the item
    item = comp.getComposerItemById(mapname)
    # Get the attr by name and call 
    return getattr(item, attrname)()
```

Then you can use this expression in your print composer labels -:

```
composeritemattr('Composer 1', 'Map 0', 'scale')
```

(Replace the values with the actual name of your composer and map window)

I have found that sometimes this returns a value like 1000.000000000001 so I wrap it in a round() function.